# FEM with soil slope

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, laminar-flow

I what to calculate displacements, stress and strain in a soil slope with a FEM script. The slope moves like a laminar flow.
Can you suggest me some bibliography on this problem?
I've already look on Zienkiewicz - The finite element method vol 1, 2 and 3-

Comment: Hi @marchetto, and welcome to scicomp!  Do you have a specific model or equation that you're trying to solve?  Or are you trying to find a suitable equation to model soil slope deformation?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I'm looking for some paper or book on FEM for soils and or laminar flows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only book I've found that treats a variety of FE methods for deformation in porous media (e.g. soils) is:

R. W. Lewis, B. A. Schrefler (1999) [The Finite Element Method in the Static and Dynamic Deformation and Consolidation of Porous Media](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471928097.html)

I don't think it covers modeling soil deformation as if it were laminar fluid.  Normally, soils are modeled as a two phase material (either fully or partially saturated with fluids).  Deformation of the solid skeleton in the soil is intimately coupled with the flow of the fluids within it (whether that be air, water, or both).  It's very hard to model one without the other.